# How to use copy() in console if opened website has a function of the same name

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, console, developer-tools

With `copy("text")` in the developer tools console of Chrome and Firefox you can copy a `"text"` without an user interaction. Is this also possible if the website I've opened also has a function named `copy`? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you refer to window overriding:**

Unfortunately, once website overrides methods from window object, they are basically gone for good.

There are some workarounds, for instance you could use proxy interceptor like Charles, inject something like `<script> window.copy_saved = window.copy; </script>` on the very top of the `<head>` tag and then use `copy_saved` method with preserved original functionality.

**If you refer to accessing functions defined in website's script tags:**

It really depends on implementation, if the method is wrapped in structure accessible in `window` object, then yes, you can find a way to invoke the method. Methods however, can be stored in closure-like objects and thus being inaccessible by outside environment. It usually takes thorough reverse engineering to find a way into minified closures.